curl: (3) bad range specification in URL position 98
when I using this command to send a post reqeust on macOS(14.3.1) with zsh :
~ ⌚ 19:56:55
$ curl -X POST https://localhost:8081/infra/alipay/notification/v1/alipaySeverNotification\?voucher_detail_list\=\[\{"amount":"0.20","merchantContribute":"0.00","name":"5折券","otherContribute":"0.20","type":"ALIPAY_DISCOUNT_VOUCHER","voucherId":"2016101200073002586200003BQ4"\}\]
curl: (3) bad range specification in URL position 98:
https://localhost:8081/infra/alipay/notification/v1/alipaySeverNotification?voucher_detail_list=[{amount:0.20,merchantContribute:0.00,name:5折券,otherContribute:0.20,type:ALIPAY_DISCOUNT_VOUCHER,voucherId:2016101200073002586200003BQ4}]

waht should I do to fixed this issue?

As curl says, that's not a valid URL. You need to URL-encode it.
Especially the [] are illegal in URLs, so curl assumes they are part of a custom logic to specify a range of values (but that's not what you're doing).
Of course, the ", zhe and the ken characters are just as illegal in URLs.
Furthermore, it would seem to me that you want to use POST, but pass the data as URL parameters. That also seems wrong.
So, you'll probably want to check first how you actually want to pass your data to the Alipay API, and then do that, correctly encoding the data.
